# how to transfer files on pen drive in phone to laptop?

Tags: applications, data-transfer, asus-zenfone-2

I need to transfer data to the laptop but none of the USB ports work. As my pen drive is dual compatible, it can be connected to mobile. To transfer data from mobile to laptop I generally use airdroid app but this app is not showing data of external pen drive. Can anyone help in accessing the pen drive files(connected to mobile) from laptop?

Thank you

Comment: If the file size is not large you can upload it on drive and access from the laptop.

Comment: Can we upload documents from pendrive (connected to mobile) to google drive?

Answer (score 0):

Some file managers have an "Access from PC" option that allows you to access your device's storage over Wi-Fi (using FTP).

For example, you could use the "Access from PC" option in the free app [File Manager +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphainventor.filemanager) (I am not associated with the developers of this app).

Alternatively, if your device is rooted, you could use ADB over Wi-Fi found in the also free app [Kernel Tuner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rs.pedjaapps.kt) (that I am also not associated with) and then press the "ADB over WiFi" button (found in MISC > ADB over Wifi or its widget), then run

```
 adb connect (enter IP address here)
```

(It will tell you what IP to enter after pressing the button).

Then, use `adb push` and `adb pull` to send and recieve files from your device.

If your device runs LineageOS (tested on LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2)), you can also edit the Quick Settings menu (the menu above the notifications) to have an "ADB over Wifi" button (so no third-party app is needed).

Comment: I want to access the pen drive storage connected to mobile. Can file manager plus does this? Thank you

Comment: @TomRiddle I just tested it and the FTP part only works with internal storage and your SD card. So to use that you would need to put the contents of your USB drive on an SD card to use that. :( But ADB Wireless works.